# multi language in modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am looking for a simple way to make a multi language site.
Is there such a thing as `chrome.i18n.getMessage()` for websites?
there may be a JS-framework that makes something like that?

Comment: Shouldn't that be done on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Jed](http://slexaxton.github.com/Jed/), a Gettext Style i18n for Modern JavaScript Apps

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a google translate widget.

Google's Translate Tools: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

Comment: I want nothing automatic. i hope there is a way to put all strings in one file pro language like in massages.json